# apt-get from private repository via https with self signed certificate failed by SSL handshake error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, apt, nexus

I'm not able to use my own apt-source via https.

Using web based repo with imported cert and key-file as apt-source.

Client:
root and intermediate cert in
*/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/*
has been imported via
*update-ca-certificates --fresh -v*.

I'm able to use *curl* and *wget* by pulling some sample files from my apt-source without ssl-probs.

Testing connection via *openssl s_client -connect nexus.local.space:8443* also seems to be OK:

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2164 bytes and written 491 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: 5FA14C91A8EC0DB36E0E28A09C4D99720E616596797047E604B9E75C96BDDF07
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 9223EDFA3DB774269D34D0C24389EA7AA264F8D35B1A8FD8AF5DEABA9B17C1ACFCE517D6D34B0EA650F5982386025569
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1604406417
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
closed
```

but apt-get update fails with:

```
*E: Failed to fetch https://nexus.local.space:8443/repository/apt-proxy-focal/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate. [IP: 130.220.254.9 8443]*
```

turning any verification off via conf in /etc/apt.conf.d/ or in sources.list doesn't solve the prob.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about that, does this help https://serverfault.com/questions/340887/using-a-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-an-https-based-internal-apt-repository